# Javascript run async method synchronously in a function

Tags: javascript

I want to create a listener function to listen changes of global variable. The use case is, when I made a ajax call, i flag `isAjaxDone` variable to `false`, once its done then flag it to `true`. So the listener will process something once detected the `isAjaxDone` is `true`.

i tried `asyc ... await` & `Promise` but i still can't achieve what i want. The entire method still run asynchronously outside, except the method inside `asyc ... await` & `Promise`.

Here is what i have tried:

```
var isAjaxDone = null
var timeout = 0
function listener(){
  let waiter = function(){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
      setTimeout(() => {
        timeout += 1
        listener()
      }, 100);
    })
  }

  if(isAjaxDone) return true
  if(isAjaxDone === null) return false 
  if(isAjaxDone === false){
    if(timeout < 300){
      return waiter()
    }
    else{
      return "timeout"
    }
  }
}
```

Implementation:

```
function checker(){
  var ajaxStatus = listner()
  if(ajaxStatus){
    //...
  }
}
```

When i call `isAjaxDone`, it will return me a Promise function instead of boolean.

I prefer not to use `Promise...then` because the function i wrote is consider as library, I don't want the user wrap a bunch of code inside the `then` because it will caused some problem to user code structure. Same goes to the `Callback`.

I would like to let it wait until either return timeout or boolean only, please advise.

Comment: Why not just do the processing in a callback of the AJAX itself? For example, instead of doing `isAjaxDone = true` when the AJAX completes, just do your processing there instead.

Comment: You probably want to wrap the AJAX within a Promise, which `resolve`s at the end of xhr.onload.

Comment: @Jerry do you have a variable scope problem? Variables have different values than what you want at the time the Ajax callback is being executed?

Comment: use Callback or Wrapping Ajax within a Promise caused my function less flexibility. I don't want wrap a bunch of code inside the `then(data=>{ //...})` and i prefer "status/variable dependency" more than  "function dependency", so user just have to check status instead of run the callback.

Comment: @ItayGrudev I prefer the `listener()` return boolean only.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('POST', yourURLHere);
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  xhr.onload = function(){
    var o = JSON.parse(this.responseText); // should be `json_encode(['testProperty' => true])`ed response
    if(o.testProperty === true){
      resolve(true);
    }
    else{
      reject(false);
    }
  }
  xhr.send(formData); // you should get used to FormData
});
promise.then(function(resolveResult){
  yourGlobalVar = resolveResult;
});
```

Of course, I would just make a post function and execute a function when all is complete, like:

```
function post(url, formData, success, successContext){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  var c = successContext || this;
  xhr.open('POST', url);
  xhr.onload = function(){
    success.call(c, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
  }
  xhr.send(formData);
  return xhr;
}
```

Now you can reuse:

```
var fd = new FormData;
fd.append('output', true);
// PHP could look like
/* if(isset($_POST['output']) && $_POST['output'] === true){
     echo json_encode(['result' => true]);
   }
*/
post('someURL.php', fd, function(resultObj){
  globalVar = resultObj.result; // should be true since we sent that
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an AJAX API that is already awaitable like [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)? It is [polyfillable](https://github.com/github/fetch).

```
const request = new Request('https://example.com', {method: 'POST', body: '{"foo": "bar"}'});
(async() => {
  const response = await fetch(request);
  return await response.json();
})()
```

Comment: I believe you forgot to declare `response`.